# Breaking the string in c#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, query-string

I have the id of the TextBoxes as tb1, tb2, tb3 and the text assignment

```
tb1.text="xyz";
```

I want it to be dynamically called which takes the value from array something like

```
tb(record[key]).text="xyz".
```

which is obviously not right. Can anyone help me how to make it happen using C#

Comment: Will there only ever be 3 textboxes? If so then you can just use some if statements. It might be good for us to know why you want to do this.

Comment: @Joey Thought to use if statements but Actually I have 16 textboxes. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FindControl` method to build the string

```
TextBox tb = FindControl("tb" + record[key]) as TextBox;
tb.Text = "xyz"
```

that might not be exactly right, but that should put you on the right track.

Comment: One problem with that is that it silently breaks when you rename the controls. This kind of magic strings in the source are an anti-pattern IMO.

Comment: Very true.  I try to avoid these situations in general though.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the textboxes into an array or dictionary and then use that to look up the correct textbox.

```
TextBox[] tb=new TextBox[]{tb1,tb2,tb3};
tb[id-1].Text="xyz"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of controls. You can then access them like so:

```
myTextBoxArray[0].Text = "xyz";
```

Or

```
myTextBoxArray[record[key]].Text = "xyz";
```

See this post for how to create arrays of controls, as one example.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/180533

Answer (score 1):

You could use FindControl method to find them, something like this:

```
TextBox test = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("tb"+record[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
Control myTb = FindControl("tb" + record[key]);
myTb.Text = "xyz";
```

Take care, though, to handle situations where the control isn't found.

[More information here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)